# How can I select rows that are older than a specific date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried using:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.admin_IVM_ITEMMAST WHERE LSTSAL_DATE <= '2016-09-31 00:00:00.000'
```

But when I execute the query i get this error.

**Error:**

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 The conversion of a char data type
>   to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

The column name is: `LSTSAL_DATE` and a typical string inside the column is: `2013-05-02 00:00:00.000`

Comment: "Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1" That's not a MySQL error thats more like a SQL server (MSSQL) error to me

Comment: This is surely mssql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are only 30 days in september!

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.admin_IVM_ITEMMAST WHERE LSTSAL_DATE <= '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: To build on this answer a little bit, and help the OP with interpreting error messages in the future: The error message indicates that "[the conversion to date] resulted in an __out-of-range datetime__ value". As Daniel's answer points out, Sep 31st is "out of range", since there are only 30 days.

Comment: And this is the part where I contemplate suicide. LOL

Answer (score 1):

you can select the date you or from access form's textbox and 20 can be written any number you want if you put 50 instead of 20 you will get people who are older than 50 years.
20 in the code could be a variable to select specific age by number

`SELECT *

FROM Table Name

WHERE ((Year(Now())-Year(date)>20));
`